# I want to set up FAUmachine virtual machine, please help

Tags: virtualization

I want to install faumachine, I have it on my system, but now, what do I do?

I would appreciate it if someone could walk me through it step by step

Answer (score 0):

As far I can understand Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS have [faumachine 20120707-3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=faumachine).

According to [official site](http://www3.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/Research/FAUmachine/download.shtml), it is latest version.

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install faumachine
```

Then you can launch it with `faum` or from launcher *FAUMachine*.

Comment: Watch out for this one. This OP says that wants to install faux machine but after that says what it means is wants to learn how to run Windows XP VM on it and after that says that doesn't have an XP installation disk and where can I get one. Extra points for anyone who can get the OP's nonexistent XP extended support. OP finally gave up and installed VirtualBox. April fools.

Comment: I do not see any mention of "Windows XP" in question. The OP could try latest release of [Redox 0.4.1](https://github.com/redox-os/redox/releases/tag/0.4.1) on faum ;)

Comment: I found this out in the comments when I tried to answer and gave up when I was asked to negotiate for a respawning of Windows XP. After that the OP posted another question about installing Windows 10 in VirtualBox.